# Hourly increment in solaris 10

Tags: shell, solaris

I have the below solaris scripts, it's working fine but I need to group the hourly increment to one line. Please see sample below.

```
#!/bin/ksh
cd /apps/ins/hourly_stat
d1=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%y%m%d`
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'00'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'01'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'02'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'03'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'04'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'05'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'06'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'07'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'08'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'09'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'10'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'11'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'12'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'13'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'14'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'15'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'16'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'17'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'18'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'19'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'20'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'21'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'22'.rep 
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'23'.rep
```

Comment: So you want to extract 4 lines from each of 24 different files... What does it mean to "group the hourly increment to one line"? Can you show us some sample input and expected output?

Comment: This is amazing am impressed with the respond and thanks for the guidance : well a plus 1hr incrementally from 00hr...23hrs sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.$d1'xy'.rep  of that will start from 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, till 23,

Comment: If you are amazed and impressed by the answers, feel free to accept one of them !

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you mean with "group the hourly increment to one line".

Perhaps this will fit the needs:

```
#!/bin/ksh
cd /apps/ins/hourly_stat
d1=$(TZ=GMT+24 date +%y%m%d)
sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.${d1}??.rep
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond but what i need actually is how to execute the sed command for yesterday from 00hrs to 23hrs at 1hr interval without the 24 lines of sed as posted command.

Comment: This is still unclear. The line I posted will execute the sed commands for the 24 hourly files. Did you try it ?

Comment: Thank you, but this only brings output for sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.13120800.rep (i.e. for 00hrs) and nothing for 01, 02, 03 till 23hrs. if this makes any sense of what i really wanted, a loop output of yesterday files from 00hrs yesterday till 23hr yesterday.

Comment: @user3070701 this answer should give exactly the same output as your longer original script. Does your script actually work? If that doesn't work, you did not explain to us the problem yet, and we cannot fix it. This answer is a correct simplification of yours, I don't see what more you want here.

Comment: @jlliagre I would write even simpler as `sed -n 20,23p SMSC_Report.$d1??.rep` but that's just me ;-) A more accurate version would be `sed -n 20,23p SMSC_Report.$d1[0-2][0-9].rep` but shell scripts are meant to be lazy, so it's fine, `??` is short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop, to iterate through each possible hour, will do what you ask.

```
#!/bin/ksh
cd /apps/ins/hourly_stat
d1=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%y%m%d`
for hr in 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
do
    sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.${d1}${hr}.rep
done
```

A more compact alternative - if your ksh supports the brace notation - is this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
cd /apps/ins/hourly_stat
d1=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%y%m%d`
for hr in {00..23}
do
    sed -n '20,23p' SMSC_Report.${d1}${hr}.rep
done
```